# Adding optional param to rewrite rule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rule in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^inc/pro(.*)$ /incl/files/share.incl.php?proj=$1 [NC,L]
```

I need to modify the rule to allow for potential additional parameters, that may or may not be present.

```
RewriteRule ^inc/pro(.*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)?/?$ /incl/files/share.incl.php?proj=$1&opt1=$2&opt2=$3 [NC,L]
```

This actually broke my original rule...

URLs that I wish to be able to handle are:

```
mydomain.com/inc/proAB2
mydomain.com/inc/proAB2/structure
mydomain.com/inc/proAB2/structure/code
```

Comment: What are some example URLs you want to handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^inc/pro(\w+)(?:/(\w+)(?:/(\w+))?)?/?$ incl/files/share.incl.php?proj=$1&opt1=$2&opt2=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Actually, I just tested and this rule did not work for some reason. I've  tried changing it to RewriteRule ^inc/pro(.*)+(?:/(.*)(?:/(.*))?)$ incl/files/share.incl.php?proj=$1&opt1=$2&opt2=$3 [NC,L] and while it worked with additional attributes, when there option attributes were missing it did not work... Still tweaking.

Comment: For which URL it didn't work and what was the need to use `.*` instead of `\w+` ?

Comment: The first one. The reason I tried (.*) because it did work in original rule but since it still does not work I suppose \w is fine as well.

Comment: I think I've got it:  RewriteRule ^inc/pro([^/]*)/?(.*)$ incl/files/share.incl.php?proj=$1&opt1=$2&opt2=$3 [NC,L]

Comment: What you expect in `$_GET['proj']` for URL:  `mydomain.com/inc/proAB2`?